# Twitter Bootstrap - 100% Height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design an Admin panel for my application using twitter-bootstrap framework but i cannot get my layout to work.

I was inspired by this design: [image]
It would be a two column layout "Sidebar" and "Main content" but I can't get the 100% height to work. I managed to get 2 column layout with 100% width using this code:

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">


   <div class="span2 colorize-white">
     <!--Sidebar content-->Sidebar
   </div>


   <div class="span10 colorize-white">
     <!--Body content-->Main
   </div>


 </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Global */
html, body {
    color: #6B787F;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #11161a;
    font-family: 'PT Sans' !important;
}

.colorize-white {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.no-margin {
    margin: 0;
}
```

I'm half way there but there are two things I can't solve.
  1)  100% Height
  2)  Getting rid of outer margins on second image

[image]
You can see that I have margin between browser border and Sidebar/Main elements and then margin between the two. I need to get rid of this if I add no-margin to all my elements in HTML i pasted including body tag i still don't get 100% height and i still cant get rid of margins between browser border and sidebar and main content while the margin space between Sidebar and Main content disappears.

Comment: Sorry, but are you looking to get the same design as the img?

Comment: No. I was looking for inspiration browsing some Admin Panel templates and this one poped up as a two column one. It's 100% width/height what I want to.

Comment: can you share the link of this design?

Comment: https://dribbble.com/shots/829195-Slate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not so sure Bootstrap's grid model is what you're looking for here. You may instead be looking for absolute positioning. For example:

```
#sidebar, #content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#sidebar { left: 0; width: 10em; }
#content { left: 10em; right: 0; }
```

**[Try it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/AgaYq/embedded/result,html,css/)**

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example that works for Bootstrap 3..

Make sure the HTML and body are both 100% height. Wrap the sidebar and content and then use `position:absolute` on the sidebar.

http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/basis

Code: http://bootply.com/86704

Comment: worked, one more question, do you know how to make it work with fixed top navbar?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, **[but here it goes.](http://jsfiddle.net/Q97xb/)**

just modified the CSS slightly. `margin:0;` to `html, body` tag.