# Jquery vertical slider doesn't occupy all the height with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, slider

here is extract of my code. As you can see in the picture below, the vertical slider does't occupy all the height (no problem with the horizontal slider). Any help ?

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Noc.png)

Thanks

```
 <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
              vide
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
             <div id="slider" ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                <div id="slider-vertical" ></div>
              </div>...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give the element css `height: 100%`

Comment: thanks Yehuda. Already tried that (even max-height: 100%) but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Found this workaround here : [Bootstrap *vertical* responsiveness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230952/bootstrap-vertical-responsiveness?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

applied to `<div id="slider-vertical" ></div>`

and it worked

[link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuedC.png)